# Is there a way to generate a random variate from a non-standard distribution without computing CDF?

Tags: c++, python, algorithm, random, montecarlo

I'm trying to write a Monte Carlo simulation. In my simulation I need to generate many random variates from a discrete probability distribution.

I do have a closed-form solution for the distribution and it has finite support; however, it is not a standard distribution. I am aware that I could draw a uniform[0,1) random variate and compare it to the CDF get a random variate from my distribution, but the parameters in the distributions are always changing. Using this method is too slow.

So I guess my question has two parts:

1. Is there a method/algorithm to quickly generate finite, discrete random variates without using the CDF?
2. Is there a Python module and/or a C++ library which already has this functionality?

Comment: Try [`std::discrete_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution).

Comment: Doesn't that require you to know the distribution?

Comment: if you have a closed-form solution, is there any chance you could invert it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acceptance\Rejection:
Find a function that is always higher than the pdf. Generate 2 Random variates. The first one you scale to calculate the value, the second you use to decide whether to accept or reject the choice. Rinse and repeat until you accept a value.
Sorry I can't be more specific, but I haven't done it for a while..
Its a standard algorithm, but I'd personally implement it from scratch, so I'm not aware of any implementations.

Comment: It's difficult to explain the rejection method with such brevity. It may be worth it to [point to a reference on the method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling)

Answer (score 4):

In the past few years, nice new tools have been added to SciPy to address this kind of problem.
You can easily generate samples from custom discrete distributions with finite support by just specifying pdf.

Overview of the different methods:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.sampling.html

For discrete distributions, the methods are `DiscreteAliasUrn` and
`DiscreteGuideTable`.

Tutorial:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/stats/sampling.html

If your parameters are varying, it is often complicated. Without knowing more about the specific problem, it is worth to try out one of the above methods.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed acceptance/rejection is the way to go if you know analytically your pdf. Let's call it f(x). Find a pdf g(x) such that there exist a constant c, such that c.g(x) > f(x), and such that you know how to simulate a variable with pdf g(x) - For example, as you work with a distribution with a finite support, a uniform will do: g(x) = 1/(size of your domain) over the domain.

Then draw a couple (G, U) such that G is simulated with pdf g(x), and U is uniform on [0, c.g(G)]. Then, if U < f(G), accept U as your variable. Otherwise draw again. The U you will finally accept will have f as a pdf.

Note that the constant c determines the efficiency of the method. The smaller c, the most efficient you will be - basically you will need on average c drawings to get the right variable. Better get a function g simple enough (don't forget you need to draw variables using g as a pdf) but will the smallest possible c.

Answer (score 0):

If acceptance rejection is also too inefficient you could also try some Markov Chain MC method, they generate a sequence of samples each one dependent on the previous one, so by skipping blocks of them one can subsample obtaining a more or less independent set. They only need the PDF, or even just a multiple of it. Usually they work with fixed distributions, but can also be adapted to slowly changing ones.

Comment: Can you give more detail on the distribution? How many samples are needed for each parameter set?